# Material-UI TextField context dirty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to better understand how to check for dirtyness using material-ui's FormControl or TextField component. The documentation for [TextField demo page](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/#components) states:

> TextField is composed of smaller components (FormControl, InputLabel,
>   Input, and FormHelperText) that you can leverage directly to
>   significantly customize your form inputs.

... and on the [TextField API docs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/#inheritance) it states:

> The properties of the `<FormControl />` component are also available.

... and later in the [FormControl API docs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/form-control/#formcontrol) it states:

> Provides context such as **dirty**/focused/error/required for form inputs.
>   Relying on the context provides high flexibilty and ensures that the
>   state always stay consitent across the children of the FormControl.
>   This context is used by the following components:
>
> FormLabel
>   FormHelperText
>   Input
>   InputLabel

---

But I don't see any documentation state exactly HOW to check for dirty using the TextField / FormControl.

Can anyone clarify? This is StackOverflow, so here is some code for the TextField I'm using:

```
<TextField
  id='email'
  label='Email'
  value={this.state.email}
  onChange={this.handleChange('email')}
  margin="normal"
  required
  fullWidth>
</TextField>
```

Answer (score -1):

Dirty checking for TextField component has to be implemented manually.

```
handleChange = (id) => (event) => { this.setState({isEmailDrity: true}); };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Formik material-ui

> [Formik Material UI](https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui)